# Does burning damage stack in any way?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am trying a guardian build which revolves around burning as many foes as possible for as much damage as possible. However, when I quickly use two burning skills, I notice only one burning icon on the foe.

**Does burning stacks in any way?** Or does casting two burning spells on the same target amount to nothing?

To elaborate a little, suppose spell A deals 100 damage over 10 seconds and spell B deals 200 damage over 10 seconds. I cast spell A, and after 5 seconds I cast spell B. What is the expected behaviour?

What is the behaviour if I cast spell B instead of spell A and vice-versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Burning, Poison, Chilled, and Crippled stack in duration instead of intensity. It will show only one stack, but if you watch you'll see the duration increase. If you apply multiple conditions with different damages, the duration will seem to increase. This, however, is no more than an attempt to unclutter the UI (user interface). Once the duration of the first condition completes, then the second condition will begin. Despite these separate durations, however, cleansing a condition will remove the entire condition (no matter the duration or intensity).

Example:

You use Skill A to burn a foe, and then Skill B to burn the same foe. Skill A's burn lasts 10 seconds, and Skill B's burn lasts 5 seconds. When applied, the burn duration will be 15 seconds. Skill A's burn will run for the listed 10 seconds, doing the damage as described in Skill A. When this finishes, Skill B's burn will start to tick, doing the damage as described in Skill B.

Comment: What about damage? If two burning spells deal different amount of damage, which damage is taken? Or... is damage directly proportional to the duration of the burn?

Comment: the third one being bleeding?

Comment: @yx. - Ah, yes, that's it!

Comment: @NathanSabruka - I'm not certain on this, but I think it takes the damage from the higher one. It might say on the wiki, but I can't access that where I am.

Comment: Bleeding stacks in intensity, as well as duration.

Comment: @Domocus - Hm, now that you mention it I do seem to recall seeing numbers on a bleeding debuff. Maybe there isn't a third one... Edit: Or perhaps there is a third and a fourth.

Comment: Bleeding stacks up to 25, if I recall correctly.

Comment: So if a ranger quickly inflicts 24 stacks bleeding on a monster and a mesmer puts one stack of high damage bleeding on that same monster, for the duration of all its stacks, it will take the higher damage?  Seems like a really powerful combo

Comment: @newuser - From what I understand, yes, that's how it would work.

Comment: For bleeding? No, the stacks are separate.

Comment: @Domocus - Wups, I keep forgetting bleeding stacks intensity instead of duration. That's how it works on duration stacking, apparently. It's a little hard to look this stuff up, as everything is blocked here. [Here](http://www.guildwarsinsider.com/beliastas-effect-stacking-breakdown/) is, I'm told, a nice graphic explaining all the stacking, but it's blocked for me.

Comment: @newuser No. Each bleeding stack is counted separately.